# Plain image to GeoTiff using GDAL

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, gdal2tiles

See the bug I posted at [GDAL](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6731) for details and a sample image.

In summary I used the QGIS georeferencer plugin to georeference a plain image file, then use gdal2tiles on it but I get an error. I took the georeference plugin out of the picture and still get the same error. Is there something wrong with the commands?

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 4461.4 1584.9 -75.8 45.45 -gcp 1415.4 1218.3 -75.95 45.52 -gcp 2279.6 353.9 -75.88 45.53 -gcp 3755.7 104.89 -75.80 45.52 original_rgb.png temp.tif

gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 temp.tif out.tif
gdal2tiles.py -z 11 out.tif tiles
```

If instead of the last line I use `gdal2tiles.py -s EPSG:4326 -z 11 out.tif tiles`, it works fine and the tiles are in the right place.

Comment: Your ground control points do not make sense with your gdalwarp command. I am pretty sure that coordinates `-75.8 45.45` are not expressed in EPSG:3857 but in EPSG:4326. You should tell for gdalwarp "Hey, my source image is georeferenced with EPSG:4326 ground control points, please warp it into EPSG:3857". Thus `gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 temp.tif out.tif`. Without -s_srs your command means that the image is already in EPSG:3857 which is OK, but then you must insert also the ground control points in EPSG:3857.

Comment: Thanks, that works. How can gdalwarp work if it doesn't know what srs it's transforming from?

Comment: Think about what happens when you warp with ground control points. It is "move this pixel to that location on a rectangular grid". That process does not care about projections. -t_srs in this case is only attaching the given projection to the result.